# we are getting the error as Response is not available in this context when we remove http header on server

Tags: c#, server, global-asax

Getting error while redirecting 'Response is not available in this context'

```
<%@ Application Language="C#" %>
<script RunAt="server">

void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Remove("Server");
}

void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //  Code that runs on application shutdown

}

void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Code that runs when an unhandled error occurs

}

void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Code that runs when a new session is started

}

void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Code that runs when a session ends. 
    // Note: The Session_End event is raised only when the sessionstate mode
    // is set to InProc in the Web.config file. If session mode is set to StateServer 
    // or SQLServer, the event is not raised.

}
```

Comment: Which line of code throws the error?

Comment: i am getting error in Application_Start

Comment: application_start event does not required to be triggered by request. Also it is only on time executing event. ASP.NET  application starts only once. After that it's all about processing requests and sending back the responses. So if you want to remove a specific header before sending every response back to the client you should write that code in `Application_BeginRequest`

Comment: same error getting on that method also

Answer (score 0):

Try move this piece of code from `Application_Start` to `Application_PreSendRequestHeaders` or even `Application_EndRequest` as below.

```
protected void Application_PreSendRequestHeaders(object source, EventArgs e)
{
      System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Remove("Server");
}
```

OR,

```
protected void Application_EndRequest()
{
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Remove("Server");
}
```

Comment: when we use above method also, we got the same error.